# How to find $\int \frac{2}{e ^{-x}+1} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

How to integrate $\int \frac{2}{e ^{-x}+1}dx$ I tried by substitution, I required by substitution, thanks.

Comment: Hint: Multiply top and bottom of your fraction by $e^{x}$

Comment: When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include your work and indicate where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Comment: You have the reason, Daniel,  but my problem this, initial part.

Answer (score 5):

This is straightforward:

$$ I = 2 \int \frac{e^x}{1+e^x} \, \mathrm{d}x $$

Can you see that the numerator is just the derivative of the denominator? What do we now about the integral $\int \frac{f'}{f} \, \mathrm{d}x$?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

HINT:
$$
\frac{1}{e^{-x}+1}=\frac{e^x}{1+e^{x}}
$$
and you can substitute $t=e^x+1$.

Comment: Certain Przemyslaw, thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

Set $u=\mathrm e^x$, $\mathrm d\mkern1mu u=u\,\mathrm d\mkern1mu x$, whence
$$I=\int\frac{2u^{-1}\mathrm d\mkern1mu u}{u^{-1}+1}=\int\frac{2\mathrm d\mkern1mu u}{1+u}.$$

Answer (score 0):

This may be obvious but I think it is good to know that $x^{-1}$ is the same thing as $\frac{1}{x}$, and in your case $e^{-x}$ is $\frac{1}{e^x}$.